# A tiring field trip

Tags: lateral-thinking, wordplay

(The simple and easy one, a small pop up in my head, while stuck in traffic)

> This field trip is making me tired...
>   I take this every year, with nothing changed
>   Only bonfire and night sky
>   I wish to stop, but he won't let me.

Can you guess who is saying this and what is this field trip about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like

> (the) EARTH

This field trip is making me tired

> the earth's journey around the sun could be seen as a trip. Maybe "field" is somehow referring to some force field

I take this every year, with nothing changed

> one trip a year as one year is described by earth surrounding the sun once

Only bonfire and night sky

> bonfire would be the sun here and night sky the dark side of the earth i.e. the 'rear' side

I wish to stop, but he won't let me.

> <strike>Could be god or some other fictional source providing the energy</strike> gravity forces the earth to stay on its orb/oval of movement

Comment: Shouldn't the last line be the sun not letting the earth escape because of its gravity?

Comment: yup, you got it :) last one needs improvement though, @Wu33o got the right idea

Comment: I thought about gravity, too. But the "he" confused me here

Comment: Well, he is 'gravitational force'

Comment: Sure, I understand your reasoning. I was just looking for something more person-like ;)

Comment: You are gonna piss off religious people xD (god or some other fictional source).